# How to limit a div to screen size even when content tries to overflow

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, overflow, styling

I am struggling to limit a div up till the bottom of my screen. Inside my body I have a structure like this.

```html
<body class="flex">
    <div class="h-screen w-48">navbar sticking to the left covering entire height with a fixed width.</div>
    <div class="h-screen flex-1 flex flex-col">
        <div class="w-full h-20">header containing heading of the page</div>
        <div class="w-full flex-1"> //covering remaining height(3rd div)
            <ul>
                <li>Item1</li>
                <li>Item2</li>
                <li>Item3</li>
                <li>Item4</li>
                ...many more items
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want the 3rd div to cover the remaining height of laptop and desktop screens and if there are lis that want to leave the screen then a scroll bar appears on the 3rd div.

If I try to give a max-height then it looks good for some screens but ugly for others(Suppose i give a max-height of 680px then it covers the screen for some sizes while for others it exceeds below the screen or it comes short of the bottom of screen). I want that the structure of 3 div to remain static on page irrespective of screen size and if content in 3rd div wants to overflow then a scrollbar appears on it.

Comment: I usually would make that third  div position relative and then absolutely position a div inside it with overflow auto - this should then only grow to the size of the screen and have it's own scrollbar if larger

Answer (score 0):

Using just css then this would be your best option I think:

```
    <body class="flex flex-row items-start w-screen">
<nav class="h-screen w-48 border-2 border-pink-500 fixed left-0 top-0 z-10">
    navbar sticking to the left covering entire height with a fixed width.
    </nav>
    <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
        <div class="flex flex-0 w-full h-20 border-2 border-blue-500 sticky top-0 ml-48 z-9 bg-white" style={{ width: 'calc(100vw - 12rem)' }}>
        header containing heading of the page
        </div>
        <div class="overflow-y-auto border-2 border-green-500  ml-48">
        //covering remaining height(3rd div)
        <ul>
                <li>Item1</li>
                <li>Item2</li>
                <li>Item3</li>
                <li>Item4</li>
                ...many more items

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This stickys your nav and header to the edges of the screen, which makes your 3rd div content appear to scroll within it's own area.
Adding `style={{ width: 'calc(100vw - 12rem)' }}` means that the header div will not overflow past the screen as it's width is set to "screen minus nav width".
Adding z-10 means those elements are always at the top and nothing will appear above it. I've added borders to make this more clear if you copy/paste it to your project to view it.

Alternatively, you could use a framework like ReactJS or NextJS to implement browser/page routing and navigation better.